# Generate RSA PKCS#1 with passphrase in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, phpseclib

I'm using PHP and securelib RSA so can I not use the `password_*` functions of PHP. Instead I log the user in with RSA keys. Both public and private key will be stored at the server, but the private one needs the passphrase. Does the above constitute a secure scheme?

Is there a way for the local machine (the browser) to generate an RSA key pair with passphrase in JavaScript? That way I can send the key safely to the server. The password will never be unprotected as I'm planning to use SSL.

Comment: Protocol questions should really be asked at http://security.stackexchange.com, not here. Before posting there, you should however create a more formalized description of your protocol. Currently you seem to have many misunderstandings about cryptography. Instead I would urge you to look at TLS with client authentication; the way it is currently looking, you will have a lot of trouble creating anything secure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly about programming but about protocol design.